# How to bind Image in Grid View on Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, datagridview, mdichild, mdiparent

I bind image to `GridView` from Resource folder.When I load that Form image will be bind.But When call that form from `MDIPARENT` form Image will not be showed.I attach image and Code below.

### Bind Image in Grid

```
DataGridViewImageColumn ic = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
 ic.HeaderText = "Payment";
 ic.Image = null;
 ic.Name = "cImg";
 ic.Width = 50;
 dtGrCustBal.Columns.Add(ic);
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtGrCustBal.Rows)
 {
      DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells[10] as DataGridViewImageCell;
      cell.Value = Properties.Resources.icon_payment_cash_small;       
 }
```

### Call Child from MDIParent

```
 CustomerBalance ChildCustBal = new CustomerBalance();
 ChildCustBal.MdiParent = this;
 ChildCustBal.Show();
```

### Screenshots

Loading from MDI parent:
[image: screenshot of loading a page from MDI parent]
Loading directly:
[image: screenshot of loading a page directly]

Comment: In what method do you have "Bind Image in Grid" code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the image is bound in the form load event handler, in case of `MDIChild` the value of the `DataGridViewImageCell` is again reset to null by the time form is shown and you don't see any image. When its not `MDChild` then the cell value is retained and you see the image. I am not clear why the reset is happening in case of `MDIChild`.

Subscribe to the form's `Shown` event and move your image binding code to that event handler. It works in both normal and `MDIchild` use cases.

Comment: @PraveenS - if it resolved your problem could you mark it as answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this, Use your project Namespace, when retrieving the image from Resource Folder.

```
DataGridViewImageColumn ic = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
ic.HeaderText = "Payment";
ic.Image = null;
ic.Name = "cImg";
ic.Width = 50;
dtGrCustBal.Columns.Add(ic);
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtGrCustBal.Rows)
 {
  DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells[10] as DataGridViewImageCell;
  cell.Value ="your namespace".Properties.Resources.icon_payment_cash_small;       
 }
```

Comment: No problem for me when i doing the same thing what you done on either way

Comment: yes.. thats why i mentioned on either case.. No issues on either case